# Using Nettys epoll implementation for Linux SocketCAN communication

Tags: netty, epoll, socketcan

I am considering the usage of Netty as basis for the [JavaCAN](https://github.com/pschichtel/JavaCAN) library, as it also uses NIO/epoll to access the Linux [SocketCAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html).

What bothers me it the fact that the Netty epoll classes are written for network (IP) communication, not for the usage of a Linux socket without any IP relation.

Even the `AbstractEpollChannel` that uses a `LinuxSocket` that is already dependent on `InetAddress` for IP communication.

What i would like to implement is a `Channel` that leverages the Netty epoll implementation but without IP communication, just a Linux socket.

I like to hear opinions whether you consider that possible or is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

This was just done as we only target "IP communication" when we implemented it. There is nothing wrong with other use-cases as well.